# How to bind to multiple keymaps with one line?

Tags: tig

I'm trying to remap/bind `G` in [tig](/questions/tagged/tig) to match vim's functionality (move to last line) in all of tig's keymaps.

I read the tigrc manpage, here's all that's mentioned about binding to keymaps

```
Keymaps
    Valid keymaps are: main, diff, log, help, pager, status, stage, 
    tree, blob, blame, refs, stash, grep and generic. Use generic to 
    set key mapping in all keymaps. Use search to define keys for 
    navigating search results during search.
```

here's what currently works, but not optimal or preferable:

```
bind  main G move-last-line
bind  help G move-last-line
bind  grep G move-last-line
```

here's what I expected would work:
`bind  generic G move-last-line` or `bind  main,help,grep G move-last-line`

PS: I feel questions of this type are more appropriate for unix stack exchange, but [there's no tag for tig there yet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tig), and there are similar questions to it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `bind generic G move-last-line` is enough. 
It works for me.